# Is it right way to create shortcode?

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I want to create a shortcode, but it creates empty `<p>` tags in the output.

I'm using the following code to avoid that problem, however I'm not sure if this is correct way. I have read that if shortcodes are added incorrectly, they create problems with WordPress core functionality, so please advice if the following method is correct.

```
function run_my_shortcode( $content ) {
    global $shortcode_tags;
    $original_shortcode_tags = $shortcode_tags;
    remove_all_shortcodes(); 
    add_shortcode( 'box', 'my_shortcode' ); 
    $content = do_shortcode( $content );
    $shortcode_tags = $original_shortcode_tags; 
    return $content;
} 
add_filter( 'the_content', 'run_my_shortcode', 7 );

//output the shortcode content
function my_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {   
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'title' => ''
       ), $atts));

    $output = '';
    $output .= "<div class='box' >";

    if (!empty($title)){
        $output .= '<h3>'.$title.'</h3>';
    }

    $output .= '<p>'. do_shortcode( $content ).'</p>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output; 
}
add_shortcode( 'box', 'my_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Not very familiar with this, but seems you are aggressive in removing all other short_codes

Comment: I got the idea from following link. Can you suggest something better? http://www.viper007bond.com/2009/11/22/wordpress-code-earlier-shortcodes/

Answer (score 0):

The codex explain, I think, very well the creation of shortcodes

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

A very basic shortcode

```
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

To use it, you just need to `[foobar]`

The first parameter on `add_shortcode`is the name of the shortcode

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts ) );

    return "foo = {$foo}";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

To use it, just use `[bartag foo="foo-value"]`